# Multithreading in C functions for Postgres

Tags: c, postgresql, multithreading

I'm reading documentation for SPI https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/spi.html And I have a few questions:

1. is there any way to use multithreading in C to connect to Postgres (via SPI or Libpq) and read data from one table? (for example, one thread reads data from 1 to 100 rows, second from 101 to 200 etc).
2. I know that Postgres can use workers (for SELECT, for example), but how SPI will react to that (if I send command "select * from table_name")

Comment: The SQL language and PostGreSQL support [pagination using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-limit.html)... so it should be easy to route different subsets of a query to different threads. I'm not sure how (if) it will improve performance, that would depend on specific use cases.

Comment: Do you expect faster execution or there is other reason for MT?

Comment: Yes, I want to work with big tables (like 1mil rows) and I want to have faster execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use multithreading in PostgreSQL backends. The system is not laid out for that, and interesting, yet undesirable, things are bound to happen if you do.

Using a custom background worker is the better idea. There is no problem with using SPI to process statements once you have attached to a database.